# Probability - intersection and union

Tags: probability

How to express a general relationship between $P(A\cup B \cup C)$ and $P(A\cap B \cap C)$, please? $A, B, C$ are phenomena of occurrence.

Is this correct?

$$P(A\cup B \cup C) = \frac{1}{2}[P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C) - P(B \cap C)]$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two events $U$ and $V$,
$$
P(U\cup V) = P(U)+P(V)-P(U\cap V).
$$

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
P\left(A\cup B\cup C\right) &= P\left(\left(A\cup B\right)\cup C\right) = P\left(A\cup B\right) + P(C)-P\left(\left(A\cup B\right)\cap C\right) = \\
&= P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B) + P(C) - P\left(\left(A\cap C\right)\cup \left(B\cap C\right)\right) = \\
&=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)+P(C)-\left[P(A\cap C) + P(B\cap C)-P(A\cap C\cap B\cap C)\right] = \\
&= P(A) + P(B) + P(C) - P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C) - P(B\cap C) + P(A\cap B \cap C)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much